# Grouping Selected Rows From Table

Tags: php, html, css, mysql, sql

[ouput image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PQix8.jpg) From the list of 32 clubs (belonging to different countries), 8 are reserved clubs. 4 clubs name have to be listed in different groups where 1st club name should be a reserved one and all 4 must be from different countries. Each time the page is refreshed, different names should appear amongst the groups.
ALL THE GROUPS MUST HAVE DISTINCT CLUB NAMES WITH EACH GROUP HAVING NO CLUB FROM SAME COUNTRY.
I made two tables: TEAMS - names of all 32 clubs and their countires , RESERVED- names of the 8 reserved clubs and their countiries 
This is the code i have.

```
<?php>
    $query = "SELECT * FROM teams, reserved ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 8 ";
    $result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
    {               
        $club = $row['club'];
        $reserved = $row['res_teams'];
        $x = 'A';
        $x++;

        echo "
            <div class='group'>

            GROUP $x </br>
            $reserved </br>
            ";

            if ($club!=$reserved)
            echo "
                $club </br> 
                $club </br>
                $club </br>
                </div>
                ";
            }
```

Comment: Could you post your current result and the desired result?

Comment: http://freshwallpapers.net/file/8744/500x338/16:9/uefa-champions-league-2015-2016-group-stage-draw_633513508.jpg  (this is the desired result - the image)

Comment: `ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 8` -> can you get 8 clubs with **no one** being a `reserved club` so what's next if that happens ? or will you get for sure 24 'non-reserved clubs' plus 8 'reserved clubs' from your query ?

Comment: There are 24 non-reserved clubs and 8 reserved clubs in the given list. A group cannot have more than one team from the same country. The first team of every group must be a reserved team.

Comment: Yes, that was clear for me, but how is it organized in DB ? what's the structure of the tables ? one table with the 8 reserved, one table with 24 non-reserved ?

Comment: one table with 8 reserved clubs and the other with all the 32 clubs. Both the tables have country details as well (to which the clubs belong to).

Comment: so another thing is that you need to separate clubs from the same country (how many from one particular country ? always the same amount ?) ?

Comment: Rather than adding info in the comments, please edit your question to include the information. Add your table schemas, and put the images inline instead of a link. Thanks!

Comment: Only 1 team from a particular country in a group.

Comment: @tanisha why are you rejecting edits? put the image inline instead of a link.